# Do all cyclic numbers(base10) have the digits 1,4,2,5,8 and 7?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I found that the first few all contain those digits. Is there a counterexample?

For reference: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_number

Comment: Try $\frac{1}{11}$

Comment: @lhf i'm not sure if you understand my question. that's not really a counterexample

Comment: [The Wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_number) has a list.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess it is likely so, but would be hard to prove.  The Wikipedia article you reference has all of them up to $100$ digits.  We can verify by eye that every one has the digits $1,4,2,8,5,7$ included.  [OEIS A001913](http://oeis.org/A001913) has a list of the primes less than $1000$ that generate cyclic numbers.  There are only $51$ with three digits.  If we view the digits as "random" the chance that a $100$ digit number is missing a given digit is $0.9^{100} \approx 2.6\cdot 10^{-5}$.  By $1000$ digits the chance is down to $10^{-46}$  The references in the OEIS entry seem to promise some idea of the density of these numbers.  We could then sum the probabilities to find a very small number.  This is certainly not a proof; however, I don't see a reasonable way to get to a proof.

Answer (score -2):

As it mentions in the Wikipedia article, cyclic numbers are related to repeating decimals. For example, 142857 corresponds with 1/7 and 1/7 = 0.142857..., 2/7 = 0.285714..., 3/7 = 0.428571..., 4/7 = 0.571428..., 5/7 = 0.714285..., and 6/7 = 0.857142... all repeat the same digits.

Consider what would happen if a cyclic number doesn't have a certain digit, in this case 2. If the cyclic number corresponds with $1/n$, no multiples of $1/n$ can equal 0.2… since the cyclic number doesn’t have the digit 2. Thus, there is a number $x$ such that $x/n < 0.2$ and $(x+1)/n \geq 0.3$. Thus, $(x+1)/n - x/n = 1/n > 0.1$. Thus, $n < 10$. The only cyclic number with an $n < 10$ is 142857, which includes all of the digits 1, 4, 2, 8, 5, and 7. Thus, all cyclic numbers have the digits 1, 4, 2, 8, 5, and 7.